# Eliminate some big values while using SSRS MAX function

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have number of tables which uses SSRS to import max values from multiple rows in each tables daily wise.
Sometimes we will get some abnormal readings which need to omit & use next max value.

Eg: I have a table with values "26,28,29,31,23,22,34,99999,27,20" in the rows.

So max value = 99999, but I need to omit this value as this is abnormal value & need to get max value as 34.

Is there any method to do in SSRS?

Or simply a solution to find out second highest value?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to create **Normalized Numbers**.

Just to validate the results, the sum of the Normalized Number should be zero +/- some precision.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeVal] int)  
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (26)
,(28)
,(29)
,(31)
,(23)
,(22)
,(34)
,(99999)
,(27)
,(20)
 

;with cte as (
Select *
      ,NormNbr=([SomeVal]-avg([SomeVal]) over()) / stdev([SomeVal]) over()
 From @YourTable
)
Delete from cte where abs(NormNbr)>1   -- You may want to tweak as needed

Select * from @YourTable
```

**The Updated Table Is**

```
SomeVal
26
28
29
31
23
22
34
27
20
```

**OR if you DON'T want to Delete the Abnormal Rows**

```
;with cte as (
Select *
      ,NormNbr=([SomeVal]-avg([SomeVal]) over()) / stdev([SomeVal]) over()
 From @YourTable
)
Select MaxValue = max([SomeVal])
 From  cte 
 Where abs(NormNbr)<=1
```

**Returns**

```
MaxValue
34
```

**EDIT:  If you were to run the query within the CTE, this is what you'd see**

[image]